# C# - validation attributes

Tags: c#, validation

I use C# MVC,
I have a list:

```
 public List<int?> SomeList { get; set; }
```

and when the user try to enter a letter instead of a number, it shows a validation error because the list's type is INT.

I want to add more validation, like "range" (not only) for the list's **items** (all of them will have the same attributes).

Can I do that? How?

Comment: The answer is in your title - with what exactly do you have a problem?

Comment: if I put [range(0,4)] before the list, it doesn't work.. I need that it will be for the items in the list, not for the list itself..

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into the source of the [rangeattribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute.aspx), and create your own attribute (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668224.aspx) that will validate a generic list with a range.

There ya go.

Comment: How does it help me for a list?

Comment: I did it! :)
I used that -
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071351/how-to-get-model-validation-to-pickup-attributes-set-on-objects-in-a-list-in-mvc

I created a new class that contains only an int field, and it has its own validation attributes, and then created a list of this class.

Answer (score 0):

You can always implement the validation yourself, especially if you want to implement arbitrary validation on various criteria

```
bool validate(int value){
    if ((value < min) || (value > max))
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create your own class that inherits from `List<T>`, then you can "hide" the Add method by declaring a new method:

```
    class TestList : List<int>
{
    public int MinValue { get; set; }
    public int MaxValue { get; set; }

    public TestList(int minValue, int maxValue)
    {
        this.MinValue = minValue;
        this.MaxValue = maxValue;
    }

    public new void Add(int item)
    {
        if (item < MinValue || item > MaxValue)
            throw new ArgumentException("Value is outside the acceptable range");

        base.Add(item);
    }
}
```

**Edit:** forgot to throw in the constructor.